# Speeding Up Reverse Lookups in Powershell

Tags: powershell, dns

In an attempt to locate old DNS record issues, I have created the Powershell function below. This works fairly well; however, it is a little slower than I was hoping for. I realize that I can bump up the throttle limit on the parallel foreach loop, but I am unsure how much is too much--not looking to flood the resolver. Can anything be done to speed this up without causing issues?

```
Function Check-DnsVersusIP {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [string]$ComputerName
    )

    begin {}

    process {
        $domain = "domain.com"

        if ($ComputerName -notlike "*.$domain") {
            $ComputerName += ".$domain"
        }

        $forwardResult = (Resolve-DnsName -Name $ComputerName).IPAddress
        $reverseResult = (Resolve-DnsName -Name $forwardResult).NameHost

        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            ComputerName = $ComputerName
            ForwardLookup = $forwardResult
            ReverseLookup = $reverseResult
            IssuePresent = ($ComputerName -ne $reverseResult)
        }
    }

    end {}
}
```

Also, if you happen to be offended by the name of the function, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Resolve-DnsName has a "-QuickTimeout" parameter, have you tried that?

Comment: @BrianReynolds, you may be onto something there. Some of the issue appears to be caused by look-up errors. I can look at adding QuickTimeout, but I also need to add some error handling so that the output doesn't get nasty if a reverse lookup fails. Suggestions with this part?

Comment: "not looking to flood the resolver" - unless you're running DNS on a RaspberryPI, or want to run 1000s of instances of this script at once, I don't think this is a realistic concern. Ask your local DNS admin if it really worries you :) For the name I'd suggest `Test-ReverseDNSAlignment`

Comment: I had an issue that led me here, however my slowness was caused by using a Shortname rather than FQDN. If `-DnsOnly` is used, `Resolve-DnsName` is unable to append DNS suffixes you have configured. I see you have code to handle this at the beginning of your process block, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Old issue I know, but for anyone else experiencing slow reverse lookups from powershell, I found the "-DnsOnly" flag worked wonders - from about 2 seconds to effectively instant.

YMMV, that might just be specific to my environment